# Is there a Transactions begin, commit and roll back type function in Entity Frameworks?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Is there a Transactions begin, commit and roll back type function in Entity Frameworks?

I have an Entity which has several one to many relationships all of which have default settings, which are added when a Item is added to the Entity.

In T-SQL I would have wrapped them all in a transaction statement so if one of them failed the whole transaction is rolled back.

I can not seem to find anything similar in Entity Frameworks, but before I start to write a delete item query for this I thought I just ask here at the wellspring of all entity Framework Knowledge.

If may very well be what I am looking for is right in front of my face but I can't see it for the trees well the rest of the code.

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 3):

Entity framework implicitly issue SQL queries when you call `SaveChanges` within a Transaction

but if you want to specify a one explicitly use a `TransactionScope`

```
using(var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
  // your EF code here 
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to add `transaction.Complete` in this code :-). Cost me the better part of a day once....

Comment: Thanks that is a great help